# Word frequency using C programming and Linked-List but frequency count is wrong

Tags: c, hash, linked-list, frequency

I am stuck and searched all over spending days on this. I need to create a word frequency program using C. For keeping track of collisions I use a linked list, but my code does not give the right frequency (for example, frequncy of "the" should be 25, but instead it's 18). What am I doing wrong?. Here is my code:

```c
void addToArr( char *str, HASH_ARR_ELEM hashArr[]){
int homeAddress = 0;
int addResult = 0;
WORD *tempWord;
homeAddress = hashFunct(str);

if(!(tempWord = (WORD*)malloc(sizeof(WORD))))
    printf("Memory Allocation Error\n"),
        exit(100);

strcpy(tempWord->str,str);
tempWord->count = 1;

if(hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr == NULL){
    // allocate memory
    if(!(hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr = (WORD*)malloc(sizeof(WORD))))
        printf("Memory Allocation Error\n"), exit(100);

    strcpy(hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr->str,tempWord->str);
    hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr->count = 1;

} else if(hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr != NULL && hashArr[homeAddress].headPtr == NULL){        

    if(strcmp(hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr->str,tempWord->str))
        hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr->count++;
    else{
        hashArr[homeAddress].headPtr = createList(cmpWord);
        if(!hashArr[homeAddress].headPtr)
            printf("\aCannot create list\n"),
            exit(100);

        addNode(hashArr[homeAddress].headPtr,tempWord);
        }
}else
    if(strcmp(hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr->str,tempWord->str))
        hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr->count++;
    else 
    {
        addResult = addNode(hashArr[homeAddress].headPtr,tempWord);
        if(addResult != 0)
            if(addResult == -1)
                printf("Memory Overflow adding node\n"),
                    exit(120);
            else
            {
                retrieveNode(hashArr[homeAddress].headPtr,tempWord,(void**)&tempWord);
                tempWord->count++;
                    printf("%s %d\n\n", tempWord->str, tempWord->count);
            }
    }
 } // end addToArr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of your problems is in the string comparison line.

`strcmp` returns `0` if the two strings are equal, which means that you're incrementing counts only when the strings are different.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly you expect if(strcmp(...)) to be true if the strings are equal. But it returns 0 if the strings are equal.

So this:

```
if(strcmp(hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr->str,tempWord->str))
```

Should be this:

```
if(!strcmp(hashArr[homeAddress].wordPtr->str,tempWord->str))
```

strcmp will tell you the position of the first difference, so any number greater than zero is going to be a difference, so 0 is all that is left for the strings being equal.